# Adding an optional checkbox to a user registration form in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, forms, checkbox, registration

I would like to add an optional checkbox to a user registration form saying "I want to be included in marketing activities and product updates". I would like to then accordingly register the user preference... is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

So far, I did not find any plugin or able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a plugin like Gravity Forms or Contact Form 7. These plugins allow you to create custom forms and include checkboxes or other form fields. Once the form is submitted, the plugin will store the user's preference in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your help! How can I add a Contact form 7 form to the default registration form? Via functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different paid plugins available that do user registration such as Gravity Forms, Fluent Forms, and WP Forms.

There is also the following free plugin for user registrations... [User Registration – Custom Registration Form, Login Form And User Profile For WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/)

However, do note that you will need to upgrade to the premium plugin (or use one of the paid plugins mentioned) if you are looking to conditionally integrate user submissions into your marketing email campaign (e.g. sync with Mailchimp).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was wondering.. can I add a checkbox to the standard Wordpress login form without installing a plugin? I would like to add a checkbox that the user has to tick if he wants to receive commercial offers from my website. I would therefore need to store in the database that he gave his consent (I need to have a proof of consent).